# Is object-oriented programming in Matlab suited to an econometric analysis workflow?

Tags: excel, matlab, oop

I have been reading about the benefits of object-oriented programming, but I cannot quite imagine how this would work for the kind of work I do in MATLAB. So far, I have mostly used scripts, functions, and structures for econometric analysis; importing and reformatting data from Excel (with some tolerance to non-standardised formatting of the Excel file); estimating a variety of models (whose specification at times differs only by a single parameter); creating and exporting figures, etc.

I am interested in the OOP paradigm because I have the impression that it may clean up my work space and reduce redundancy. However, all examples I have encountered pertain to applications that allow for a straightforward identification of which "objects in the real world" can be implemented as instances of a class in OOP. For econometrics, data analysis, and the like, I don't fully understand where the benefits of OOP would come in. I don't even know what would be the objects in my workflow (apart from the obvious model objects, which could just as well be structures).

If someone could outline whether and how OOP is applicable and valuable to an econometrics or general data analysis workflow, that would help me a lot.

Comment: Using OOP in Matlab doesn't mean that you need to eschew regular functions or scripts or structures. Use the right tool for the job. You're right about model objects – Matlab's [Econometrics toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/index.html) and [Financial toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/index.html) both take advantage of OOP for this. This question is probably too broad a may also be marked as leading to "primarily opinion-based" answers.

Comment: The trend is actually moving away from OOP and I read on quora many more question highlighting its misuse. I reckon OOP for financial research is one of those cases of misuse, you do not really need to retain state. Also, functions already keep the workspace clean and reduce redundancy. The data management aspect might benefit from OOP, and for that there is `table()`, which I am extending/fixing at https://github.com/okomarov/tableutils. My experience with the toolboxes mentioned by horchler, is that performance-wise, the OOP implementation is poor.

Comment: I'm not looking for opinion-based answers; instead, my problem is that I don't understand OOP well enough to see how it could be applied in the specific workflow I described. That is why I was hoping for an example of how OOP and data analysis could go together. Then I could judge for myself whether the benefits outweigh the cost of familiarising myself with using classes in MATLAB; no subjectivity involved in the answer as it pertains only to how classes may be used in the workflow described (not whether this is good or bad).

Comment: There is no single workflow on how to define classes with respect to your research goal, hence it's opinion based, as is my previous comment. I'd say, if you need to retain state, then OOP is definitely useful, if not, probably it's a matter of taste if to go with a class instead of a package of functions.

Comment: In case the problem is understanding of OOP, you should probably do some reading first. I would stay away from OOP unless I had to use it in this case. I would say that the methods matlab has should be enough for most types of data analysis. In case these are not enough, Matlab have some classes/types to simplify. However, this is only my opinion. I believe classes is mainly useful for encapsualtion or inheritance, but some experieced Java programmer may have other opinion. This is why the other comments state that this question is opinion based.

Comment: If you haven't chosen yet, I would strongly suggest using Python instead which is a proper programming language with proper OOP facilities in place.